# Create custom message box in c# for game

Tags: c#

i wanted to make custom message box in c# for a game, what i know is the message box already built-in in the windows forms as like this:

[image]

and i wanted to make it like this to be used in my game:

[image]

and maybe this not related question, but what do you guys think if programmer make a game in c# using windows forms? If that is a bad idea, what other option do you have to create a game with c# and visual studio alone (alone means not using any software than that)

Comment: @jstq is that necessary? I agree WPF might be a better option but this is no constructive commentary.

Comment: I have update my answer, take a look at it and save needless work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

Just use a normal form that you design at your hearts desire and name it `AlertDialog`. The Visual Studio built-in WindowsForm designer is well suited for this task. Then show it in a *modal* fashion when you need it:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    // ... tons of beautiful game code

    public void Alert(string message)
    {
        AlertDialog dialog;

        dialog = new AlertDialog(message);
        dialog.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

More here: [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your second question:
If you are looking to make a game with c# and visual studio alone and if you have no previous experience with game development, I would recommend using Microsoft's XNA framework. The reason is that it gives you the ability to learn and implement all the basics of 2d and 3d game development with ease and simplicity you would expect from microsofts framework. Keep in mind that XNA is no longer actively being developed by microsoft, but it is still a great tool for learning and practice purposes.

Comment: and lets say if i have a experience with game development? because i just made a games before using flash, unity and made a system in c# (could be said that i am made a game with helper which is engine, and i am new to make a game in c# and visual studio alone, because right now i am in a team and wanted to make a game in c# and visual studio alone, maybe something like side scrolling game in c# and visual studi alone

Comment: Your options are limited if you choose c# as your main language for game development. There are some 3rd party libraries out there like [link](http://ascend3d.codeplex.com/). But I used XNA in the past and I know its one of the most popular choices when it comes to C# game development.